# blinking a led using timer 1 overflow interrupt in atmega328p

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega

I'm trying to blink a led using ISR for 3seconds, here atmega328p is used. I'm trying to create a 1second delay in isr using TIMER1(16 BIT) and then loop that for 3seconds. LED is connected to PD7, I don't know why it is not blinking, can anyone point out the mistake. I'm using simulIDE, here is the circuit,[timer_circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clZ9O.png)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define SET_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT |= (1<<BIT)
#define CLR_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT &= ~(1<<BIT)
unsigned int count = 0;
void timer()
{
  TCCR1A = 0x00; // Normal mode of operation
  TCNT1 = 0xC2F8; // decimal value is 49912
  TCCR1B |= ((1 << CS10) | (1 << CS12));
  TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS11); //1024 prescaler

  sei(); // Global interrupt
}

int main(void)
{
    SET_BIT(DDRD,PD7);
    timer();
    while(1)
    {
        TIMSK1 |= TOIE1;
        if(count>=3)
        {
            SET_BIT(PORTD,PD7);
            count=0;
        }
    }
    ;
    return 0;
}
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear the interrupt. That usually involves either writing to a control register, or is a side-effect of reading/writing a particular data register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code never turn off the LED ... once the bit is set your code never clear it ... try to toggle the bit instead of set it

```
#define toggle_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT ^= (1<<BIT) //this will flip the bit
...
if(count>=3)
  {
     toggle_BIT(PORTD,PD7);
     count=0;
     TCNT1 = 0xC2F8; // reset counter
  }
```

#### update

1. use `volatile` access modifier before count variable to tell the compiler that you will Chang it from **ISR** to make sure that `count` variable will not delete in optimization
2. when you set `TCCR1B` you have to set other bits to zero to operate in normal mode
3. Recalculate value `TCNT1` for **8 MHz** which is internal default frequency

#### full code

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define toggle_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT ^= (1<<BIT) //this will flip the bit
#define SET_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT |= (1<<BIT)
#define CLR_BIT(PORT,BIT) PORT &= ~(1<<BIT)

volatile unsigned int count = 0;

void timer()
{
    TCCR1A = 0x00; // Normal mode of operation
    TCNT1 = 64754; // over flow after 1 sec calculated at 8 MHZ
    TCCR1B = ((1 << CS10) | (1 << CS12)); //1024 prescaler
    TIMSK1 |= 1<<TOIE1; // Enable timer1 overflow interrupt
    sei(); // Global interrupt
}

int main(void)
{
    SET_BIT(DDRD,PD7);
    timer();
    while(1)
    {
        
        if(count>=3)
        {
            toggle_BIT(PORTD,PD7);
            count=0;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    count++;
    TCNT1 = 64754; // reset to over flow after 1 sec calculated at 8 MHZ
}
```

Comment: Error is LED is not turning on itself, I have added the circuit in the question, can you refer it

Comment: @saravanan I have updated the answer ... tell me if the problem still exist